# dealing with Large data frame in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame in R that is 2.7 million rows and 22 columns and it is 388 MB. This data frame contains data that I want to subset. In fact I have to subset it about 100,000 times. What is the best way to do this. Right now I use a data frame and it is too slow. It takes about 1 second per iteration.  Thank you. here is toy code:

```
s<-c(100,100,100,800,800,6662,33565,265653262,266532)
p<-c(5,5,5,10,10,10,8,9,10)
name<-c("bob","bob","bob","ed","ed","ed","joe","frank","ted")
time<- as.POSIXct(as.character(c("2014-10-27 18:11:36 PDT","2014-10-27 18:11:37 PDT","2014-10-27 18:11:38 PDT","2014-10-27 18:11:39 PDT","2014-10-27 18:11:40 PDT","2014-10-27 18:11:41 PDT","2014-10-27 19:11:36 PDT","2014-10-27 20:11:36 PDT","2014-10-27 21:11:36 PDT")))
dat<- data.table(s,p,name,time)
dat #here is the data frame in reality it has 2.7 million rows and 22 cols
```

here is the subset. In this toy model I only perfrom the subset once but
in reality I have a loop with 100k iterations and each time through the loop 100,5,bob, and the # times will change

```
  result <- subset(dat,    as.numeric(s) == 100
                   &  p == 5
                   &  name  == "bob"
                   & time >= "2014-10-27 18:11:36 PDT"
                   & time <= "2014-10-27 18:12:00 PDT"
                   )
  result
```

How can this subsetting be made faster? I tried data.table() instead of data.frame but it is still slow

Comment: How is this different from [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27193662/subsetting-using-data-table-instead-of-data-frame)?  Why do you have to subset 100k times?  Have you looked into `split`ting the data?  If you have to subset 100k times, then you may want to re-think your process.

Comment: subsetting is part of the requirement. How would splitting the data help?

Comment: Can I do this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27195518/create-name-of-vector-dynamically?

Comment: To speed things up, look into the doParallel package. Depending on the cores on your machine, you can cut down on processing time significantly. If you'd like, I can provide an example.

Comment: @ jason an example would be awesome. Thank you.

Comment: @jason will it work on a windows machine?

Comment: I removed my answer as found folk already provided you `data.table` solution  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27193662/subsetting-using-data-table-instead-of-data-frame.  `data.table` is fast and memory efficient. Suggest to give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple doParallel example:

```
library(doParallel)
data(iris)
species.split <- split(iris, iris$Species)
cl <- makeCluster(detectCores())
registerDoParallel(cl)

species.models <- foreach(i=species.split) %dopar% {
    m<-lm(i$Sepal.Length ~ i$Petal.Width*i$Petal.Length);
    return(m)
}
```

For you, it would probably be a foreach on the different subsets you define so something like:

```
split=c('bob','james','jones')
foreach(i=split) %dopar% {
    result<-subset(dat,name==i)
    assign(paste0('dat',i),result)
}
```